# Swift - AVAudioPlayer still playing sound when device is on silent?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, avaudioplayer, silent

I am making a fairly basic app and have been exploring the use of AVAudioPlayer to play sound in my app, but I am having an issue where it plays sound even when the device is on silent. This is the code I am using:

```
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
```

Then in View did load:

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)
var error:NSError?
var beepOne = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("menu", ofType: "wav")!)
audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: beepOne, error: &error)
audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
```

And when the sound is played:

```
audioPlayer.play()
```

What do I need to do to stop the sound from playing when the device is on Silent or switched to silent? Perhaps before `audioPlayer.play()` an if statement that detects whether the device is in silent or not?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Found what was wrong, in the second and third lines of code:

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)
```

I had to change `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` to `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient`

Hope this helps others who might be having the same problem :)

Comment: Does this still work for iOS 10? It didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add a solution using swift 2.0 which requires try/catch error handling. There's a great article on this [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/new-syntax-swift-2-error-handling-try-catch).

```
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient, withOptions: .DuckOthers)
    } catch {
        print("AVAudioSession cannot be set")
    }
```

This post was to silence audio playback if the phone is muted. I wanted to do the opposite and indeed if you replace AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient above with AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, your audio will play even if the phone is muted.